# Compress logs rotated with cronolog

Tags: centos, logging, log-files, cronolog

I have a bunch of servers(Centos 5.x) with Apache that have their logs rotated with cronolog. What is the best strategy for compressing and deleting those logs automatically after a certain time? 
CustomLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /var/log/httpd/my.examplehost.com/access_log-%Y%m%d" common

I was thinking of creating a cron script that just says

```
gzip /var/logs/httpd/my.examplehost.com/*
```

But doesn't that also try to compress the file the apache is currently writing to? On cronolog homepage there is only mention that you should write your on cron jobs or similar but no instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use [logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) which will do what you want natively ?

Comment: That's how our servers are set up with. Lots of other software rotate logs also without logrotate, for example Tomcat, so solution to this could also solve those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logrotate really is the tool for this job but if you can't use it then you could use `find` and the `-ctime`  patameter

```
find /var/logs/httpd/my.example.host.com/ -ctime +0 -not -name '*.gz' -exec gzip {} \;
```

should do what you want as it finds files that were changed >24hours ago that arean't already compressed and compresses them.

To ensure the file you are working on isn't still open you could do something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in $(find /var/logs/httpd/my.example.host.com/ -ctime +0 -not -name '*.gz')
do
    lsof | grep $file
    if [$? -eq 1 ]
    then
        gzip $file
    fi
done
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know you could set -not on the find parameters! But it seems like it isn't necessary because gzip detects files that are already compressed.

I ended up modifying your script to compress files that are a week old saved it under /etc/cron.daily/ to run it every night. Works great.

Comment: I don't think that `-ctime +0` is correct to say 24 hours. It should be `-ctime 1`. «File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago.» from `man find`.